# This version of the application is not configured for billing through google play in react-native-iap

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, google-play-console, react-native-iap

I have used react-native-iap-12.10.5 and add license tester in google play console and when used getProduct all device , we are able to get the productList , but when want to purchase sucessfully purchased every where except android 13 devices (i have tested 2 android 13 ) in android 13 when want to purchase the pop-up shows that
"This version of the application is not configured for billing through google play"
and the log error shows
"{"code": "E_DEVELOPER_ERROR", "debugMessage": "Please ensure the app is signed correctly.", "message": "Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment.", "responseCode": 5}"
and my code for purchase is

```
 try {
          await RNIap.requestPurchase({skus: [skus]})
            .then(async result => {
              console.log('IAP req product ===>++', result);
              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                
              } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
               
              }
            })
    
            .catch(err => {
              console.log("err2",err);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("err3",err);
        }
```

please help i have not get whats going wrong here?

Comment: Why there no one reply for help any reason?

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744971/google-play-billing-library-developer-error-code-5-if-i-want-to-consume-or-ackno) can help you in some way. Please update us if it works, preferably writing your solution as an answer.

Comment: If nothing works, do these things: reboot phone, force stop (maybe doing clear data instead) Play Store, logout then login to Play store.